# Using Constructor v/s static method for basic linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures

I've tried implementing a basic linked list in my first try I implemented a static method (insert) for inserting data and pointer to the next element like shown below:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        int data = NULL;
        Node* next = nullptr;
        Node(){}
        
        static void insert(int data, Node* next,Node* obj){
            obj->data = data;
            obj->next = next;
        }
        static void printList(Node* n){
            while(n != nullptr){
                cout << n->data << " ";
                n = n->next;
            }
        }
};




int main()
{
    Node* head = nullptr;
    Node* second = nullptr;
    Node* third = nullptr;
    head = new Node();
    second = new Node();
    third = new Node();
    
    

    //via static method
    Node::insert(1,second,head);
    Node::insert(2,third,second);
    Node::insert(3,nullptr,third);
    
    Node::printList(head);
    
    delete head;
    delete second;
    delete third;
    return 0;
}
```

it's working fine as I expect (getting output as 1 2 3), but when I implement it using
constructors like show below:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class Node{
    public:
        int data = NULL;
        Node* next = nullptr;
        Node(){}
        Node(int data, Node* next){
             this->data = data;
             this->next = next;
        }
        
        static void printList(Node* n){
            while(n != nullptr){
                cout << n->data << " ";
                n = n->next;
            }
        }
};




int main()
{
    Node* head = nullptr;
    Node* second = nullptr;
    Node* third = nullptr;
    

    //via constructors.
    head = new Node(1,second);
    second = new Node(2,third);
    third = new Node(3,nullptr);
    
    Node::printList(head);
    
    delete head;
    delete second;
    delete third;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output as 1 0. When I call constructor from third to head it's working fine (by that I mean)

```
third = new Node(3,nullptr);
second = new Node(2,third);
head = new Node(1,second);
```

Kindly explain why is it behaving like that.
Note: I am a beginner in programming.

Comment: Do you understand why `int x = 1; Node* head = new Node(x, nullptr); x = 1234;`does *not* change the `int` value in the node but only the value of `x`? (There is nothing special about pointers.)

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't use `NULL` when you mean the integer `0`.

Comment: @molbdnilo yeah got it. But what's happening in the case of that insert method? I am not able to differentiate that difference? can you explain what's happening in the case of the insert method according to the same logic you said in the case of constructor?

Comment: @molbdnilo noted I won't use NULL when I mean integer 0.

Comment: Your default `Node` constructor doesn't initialise the members

Comment: You should probably think about why you are using `new` *six* times when you only want three nodes. (The small-step "initialize, then assign, then reassign" sequence is popular with beginners, but surprisingly tricky to get right. It is better to initialize variables with the value you want from the start. If you do that, you will find that your failing order is imposssible to write.)

Comment: @AlanBirtles yeah I forgot to remove that in the first case because I edited that code(I need that default constructor in the second case). Thank you. Excuse my editing mistake.

Comment: @molbdnilo yeah noted I removed that in an edit. can you explain that static method? why it's working correctly?

Comment: also don't use `NULL` when you mean `nullptr`. Actually, never use `NULL` ;)

Comment: It's difficult to explain why it works, as it's not clear what you find mysterious. Perhaps you should try the classic "draw boxes and arrows on paper" method.

Comment: @molbdnilo in the case of static method insert we are passing the object itself as an argument. For example, we are passing head before even assigning data of the second node, when we pass (insert) the second node and continue it's working fine.  I understand your first comment, my doubt is what's unique in that insert method so that it works even after passing head first (inserting when the value of second is set to nullptr then changed in next step by assigning data) it works fine?

Comment: You're not passing *the objects themselves*, you're passing pointers to objects. In the failing version, you are modifying those pointers *after* storing their values in a node. (The static version is broken after your update, by the way - it doesn't create any nodes at all. If it "works", it's because of undefined behaviour.)

Comment: @molbdnilo yes after passing as pointer,  when I pass head as a pointer (insert method) and second as a pointer for next parameter, during that time second's data is NULL (0),  then next step I inserted the second node. According to the first-line head's next is pointing towards 0, how does it update when I add the second's data via the insert method in the next line?(according to the logic you explained in the first comment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's inline `insert`:

`Node::insert(x, a, b)` is equivalent to

```
b->data = x;
b->next = a;
```

Thus,

```
Node::insert(1,second,head);
Node::insert(2,third,second);
Node::insert(3,nullptr,third);
```

is equivalent to

```
head->data = 1;
head->next = second;
second->data = 2;
second->next = third;
third->data = 3;
third->next = nullptr;
```

Now `head->next` points to the same node as `second` points to, and `second->next` to the same node as `third` - you could also write

```
head->next = second;
head->data = 1;
head->next->next = third;
head->next->data = 2;
head->next->next->next = nullptr;
head->next->next->data = 3;
```

In the failing case, `second` does not keep pointing to the node you linked `first` to; it points to a new Node.
Since you assign new values to `second` and `third`, it is equivalent to

```
head = new Node(1,second);
Node* fourth = new Node(2,third);
Node* fifth = new Node(3,nullptr);
```

and now you see pretty much immediately why it doesn't work.

You could also draw a "boxes and pointers" diagram.
(Beginners are very reluctant to do this. Don't be. It's much faster than debugging.)

Let's look at the failure:

```
head = new Node(1, second);

 head     second
  |          |
  v          v
+---+      +---+
| -------->| X |
+---+      +---+
```

then

```
second = new Node(2,third);

 head                 second     third
  |                     |          |
  v                     v          v
+---+      +---+      +---+      +---+
| -------->| X |      | -------->| X |
+---+      +---+      +---+      +---+
```

Now the node that `head->next` points to is different from the one `second` points to - it still points to the default-initialized `Node` you crated first.

While part of the working one looks like:

```
second = new Node(2, third);

second    third
  |          |
  v          v
+---+      +---+
| -------->| X |
+---+      +---+
```

```
first = new Node(1,second);

 head      second     third
  |          |          |
  v          v          v
+---+      +---+      +---+
| -------->| -------->| X |
+---+      +---+      +---+
```

Now, if you don't do this in a "as small steps as possible" fashion, your working constructor code could be written

```
Node* third = new Node(3,nullptr);
Node* second = new Node(2,third);
Node* head = new Node(1,second);
```

but the broken one won't compile when you write it like that, and you can spot that there is a dependency problem even without compiling:

```
Node* head = new Node(1,second); // second is undeclared
Node* second = new Node(2,third);  // third is undeclared
Node* third = new Node(3,nullptr);
```

which is yet another reason to get comfortable with taking bigger steps.

Comment: Thank you sir, you've explained it to the point, yeah next time I'll use box and pointer representation rather than debugging.